# How to convert a Double to a Foreign.C.Types.CInt

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am trying to set `initialWindowSize` which takes a `Graphics.UI.GLUT.Size` based on the output of another function with returns some `Double`s.

First I stupidly plugged in my `Double`s and of course I get this:

```
Couldn't match type `Double' with `Foreign.C.Types.CInt'
Expected type: GLsizei
  Actual type: Double
In the first argument of `G.Size', namely `x'
In the second argument of `($=)', namely `G.Size x y'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: initialWindowSize $= G.Size x y
```

I can't seem to find any functions which will allow me to convert my `Double`s into `CInt`s

I tried `toInteger` but I get:

```
Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Foreign.C.Types.CInt'
```

What is the right way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
round (2.25 :: Double) :: CInt
```

Or even better:

```
round (2.25 :: Double) :: GLsizei
```